# Php/javascript/mysql new post per line

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Im trying to make a textarea where you put in a list of things, all separated by a new line, and they all go into a mysql table as separate posts, how can I make this list of items go in as new posts into the table without posting them all separately, as I have like 70 items to enter.

Do you suggest I separate them all by javascript then post them by ajax one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in php:

```
$arrayOfLines = explode("\n", $_POST['mytextarea']);
```

Then you should be able to foreach through that array and put each line in the DB.

(edit - changed from split to explode based on comments)

Comment: Please do not use the deprecated `split()` function - you don't need/want a regex here anyway (if you did, the preferred function would be `preg_split()`). Use `explode()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i've understand:

The Value in textarea if entered with line breaks is stored in database as values seperated with \n. So if you want to retrieve them as you inserted it you should use **[nl2br function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_nl2br.asp)**.

```
<?php
   echo nl2br("Line 1.\nLine 2.");
?>

//Output

Line 1.
Line 2.
```

Maybe you are looking for this:

Or if you want to split the values through line breaks you can create an array like this:

```
$array = explode("\n", $_POST['textarea_value']);
```

and the loop through the $array to insert into database.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You need `"\n"` with double quotes. PHP does not parse escape sequences in single-quotes strings.